# Altair histogram, is it possible to give a name to the mark_rule?

Tags: python, plot, altair

I have a dataframe and I plot the following plot.

[image]

The code is this:

```
import altair as alt
alt.renderers.enable('default')

base = alt.Chart(df_800).properties()

bar = base.mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('volumechange', bin=True, title='Volume Change'),
    y='count()'
)

rule = base.mark_rule(color='red').encode(
    x='mean(volumechange)',
    size=alt.value(5)
)

rule2 = base.mark_rule(color='orange').encode(
    x='median(volumechange)',
    size=alt.value(5),
)

bar + rule + rule2
```

I want to add a legend or something like that to show that red rule is the mean of the volume change and orange is the median. This is the first time I am using altair, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Legends in Altair are auto-generated from color encodings, so the trick is to get your aggregates into a format where their label is a column encoded by color. Here's one way you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_800 = pd.DataFrame({'volumechange': np.random.randn(100)})

base = alt.Chart(df_800)

bar = base.mark_bar(color='lightgray').encode(
    x=alt.X('volumechange', bin=True, title='Volume Change'),
    y='count()'
)

aggregates = base.transform_aggregate(
    mean='mean(volumechange)',
    median='median(volumechange)',
).transform_fold(
    ['mean', 'median']
).mark_rule().encode(
    x='value:Q',
    color='key:N'
)

bar + aggregates
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this but in the key I get circle markers not line. I used exactly the same code, how can I fix this?

Comment: Update your renderer to the most recent version of Vega-Lite.

Comment: Is it possible to make the rules thicker? I tried adding thickness and width in mark_rule() but they didn't change anything.

Comment: Yes, you can either use a ``size`` encoding as you did in your original code, or you can pass a ``size`` argument to ``mark_rule()``.

Comment: How can I change the color of aggregates?

Comment: You can read about customizing color scales in the docs: https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#customizing-colors